How to increase docker disk space for apprunner aws?
I'm running my application on aws apprunner. With 2vCPU and 4Gib memory. It runs successfully..but after some time...i get error.
Failed to update prerender cache for [
    Error
    : ENOSPC: no space left on device, write] {

Though i metrics it shows i'm using just 40 gb of memory.
my docker imaage is just 400 mb.
